# Architecture setup for constantly changing text, property files? In a Java EE environment

Tags: java, internationalization, jakarta-ee, resourcebundle

In a Java EE environment, we are normally used to storing text in a property/resource file.  And that property file is associated with some view HTML markup file.  E.g. if your label 'First Name' changes to 'Full Name' on a HTML page, you could use the property to make that update.

```
firstName=First Name
someOtherData=This is the data to display on screen, from property file
```

If you are in an environment, where it is difficult to update those property files on a regular basis, what architecture are developers using to change text/label content that would normally reside in a property file?  Or let's say you need to change that content before redeploying a property file change.  A bad solution is to store that in a database?  Are developers using memcache?  Is that usually used for caching solutions?

**Edit-1** A database is really not designed for this type of task (pulling text to display on the screen), but there are use-cases for a database.  I can add a locale column or state field, also add a column filter by group.  If I don't use a database or property file, what distributed key/value solution would allow me to add custom filters?

**Edit-2** Would you use a solution outside of the java framework?  Like a key/value datastore?  memcachedb?

Comment: From reading again your question and from your comments on Paweł Dyda response, I don't yet undestant why you want to add a database (and even a NoSQL cluster, with all maintenance cost included). I guess we don't have the real use case yet. Is it a deployement problem (keep server up to date) ? Is it a customisation problem (several servers instance diverge in their location content even for the same key and from offical release) ? What are the constraints ? How much data ? 1MB ? 1GB ? 1TB ? How often does it change ? Synchronization must be instantaneus ? Or done each day, month, year ?

Comment: You used distributed word several time... Why ? What is really distributed in reality ? What would be the benefit ? Who would be the master source of trust if any ?

Comment: Distributed in the sense that the information may need to come from a remote location, not the web server that is serving the property file data.  Like a clustered database or memcachedb or something remote from the web application server.  In terms of data, not a lot, maybe 1000 keys and values that are static.  The data is simple text, firstName=First Name.  It may change everyday.  It doesn't have to be distributed...but it is.  Trust?  It isn't that complicated.

Comment: I could and we do use a database.  But that isn't standardized.  I guess I could create a table with:  Create table SomeNonStandardKeyName, SomeNonStandardValue.  Plus, the data is non-relational so is a relational database need?  We can't undeploy the web application and modify a property file (the file system approach).

Comment: From the amount of data you need, you just need to load your property file at startup by specifying a remote URL. Data is cached in JVM memory. Depending on your workflow you then have a background process that check for update on a regalar basis (let say each minute, hour, whatever is enough for you) or have a "button" in administration "refresh location data" you press when you want the application to update. No need for database. No need for memcached, no need for NoSQL. a simple URL accessible from production server. In term of security and dev it is easier, faster and more flexible.

Comment: Hmm, that would work actually.  Good idea.  You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I want to assure you that if you need constant changes on localized texts, for example they tend to differ from deployment to deployment, database is the way to go. Well, not just the database, you need to cache your strings somehow. And of course you wouldn't want to totally re-build your resource access layer, I suppose.

For that I can suggest extending `ResourceBundle` class to automatically load strings from database and store it in `WeakHashMap`. I choose `WeakHashMap` because of its features - it removes a key from the map when it is no longer needed reducing memory footprint. Anyway, you need to create an accessor class. Since you mentioned J2EE, which is pretty ancient technology, I will give you Java SE 1.4 compatible example (it could be easily re-worked for newer Java, just put @Override when needed and add some String generalization to Enumeration):

```
public class WeakResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {
    private Map cache = new WeakHashMap();
    protected Locale locale = Locale.US; // default fall-back locale

    // required - Base is abstract
    // @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        if (cache.containsKey(key))
            return cache.get(key);

        String value = loadFromDatabase(key, locale);
        cache.put(key, value);

        return value;
    }

    // required - Base is abstract
    // @Override
    public Enumeration getKeys() {
        return loadKeysFromDatabase();
    }

    // optional but I believe needed
    // @Override
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    // dummy testing method, you need to provide your own
    // should throw MissingResourceException if key does not exist
    private String loadFromDatabase(String key, Locale aLocale) {
        System.out.println("Loading key: " + key
                + " from database for locale:"
                + aLocale );

        return "dummy_" + aLocale.getDisplayLanguage(aLocale);
    }

    // dummy testing method, you need to provide your own
    private Enumeration loadKeysFromDatabase() {
        return Collections.enumeration(new ArrayList());
    }
}
```

Because of some strange ResourceBundle's loading rules, you would actually need to extend `WeakResourceBundle` class to create one class each for supported languages:

```
// Empty Base class for Invariant Language (usually English-US) resources
// Do not need to modify anything here since I already set fall-back language
package com.example.i18n;

public class MyBundle extends WeakResourceBundle {

}
```

One supported language each (I know it sucks):

```
// Example class for Polish ResourceBundles
package com.example.i18n;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MyBundle_pl extends WeakResourceBundle {

    public MyBundle_pl() {
        super();
        locale = new Locale("pl");
    }
}
```

Now, if you need to instantiate your `ResourceBundle`, you would only call:

```
// You probably need to get Locale from web browser
Locale polishLocale = new Locale("pl", "PL");
ResourceBundle myBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
                "com.example.i18n.MyBundle", polishLocale);
```

And to access the key:

```
String someValue = myBundle.getString("some.key");
```

Possible gotchas:

1. `ResourceBundle` requires Fully Qualified Class Name (thus the package name).
2. If you omit `Locale` parameter, default (which means Server) `Locale` would be used. Be sure to always pass `Locale` while instantiating `ResourceBundle`.
3. `myBundle.getString()` could throw `MissingResourceException` if you follow my suggestion. You would need to use try-catch block to avoid problems. Instead you may decide on returning some dummy string from database access layer in the event of missing key (like `return "!" + key + "!"`) but either way it should probably be logged as an error.
4. You should always attempt to create Locale objects passing both language and country code. That is just because, languages like Chinese Simplified (zh_CN) and Chinese Traditional (zh_TW) for example, are totally different languages (at least in terms of writing) and you would need to support two flavors of them. For other countries, ResourceBundle will actually load correct language resource automatically (note that I have created `MyBundle_pl.java`, not `MyBundle_pl_PL.java` and it still works. Also, ResourceBundle would automatically fall-back to Enlish-US (`MyBundle.java`) if there is no resource class for given language (that is why I used such a strange class hierarchy).

---

**EDIT**

Some random thoughts about how to make it more *awsome*.

**Static factories (avoid using ResourceBundle directly)**

Instead of directly instantiating the bundles with ResourceBundle, you could add static factory method(s):

```
public static ResourceBundle getInstance(Locale aLocale) {
    return ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.i18n.MyBundle", aLocale);
}
```

If you decide to change the name of `WeakResourceBundle` class to something more appropriate (I decided to use `LocalizationProvider`), you could now easily instantiate your bundles from consuming code:

```
ResourceBundle myBundle = LocalizationProvider.getInstance(polishLocale);
```

**Auto-generated resource classes**

Localized `MyBundle` classes could be easily generated via building script. The script could be either configuration file or database driven - it somehow needs to know which Locale are in use within the system. Either way, the classes share very similar code, so generating them automatically really makes sense.

**Auto-detecting Locale**

Since you are the one that implement the class, you have full control of its behavior. Therefore (knowing your application architecture) you can include Locale detection here and modify `getInstance()` to actually load appropriate language resources automatically.

**Implement additional Localization-related methods**

There are common tasks that needs to be done in Localized application - formatting and parsing dates, numbers, currencies, etc. are usual examples. Having end user's Locale in place, you can simply wrap such methods in LocalizationProvider.

Gee, I really ***love*** my job :)

Comment: I am OK with the database.  But still, is there no standard system explicitly for remote/distributed dynamic property files?  I always hear about key/value noSQL solutions like Cassandra and memcachedb, but they aren't used for key/value problems like property files in a J2EE environment.

Comment: I am working on I18n for quite a few years now and as you can imagine property files as well as `ResourceBundle` class are key ingredients of my day to day job. Yet, still I haven't heard of anyone who would use noSQL in this context. I guess it would be non-standard solution, but of course you can use it. The only problem I see is how you would resolve Localized text? What about language fall-back?

Comment: Localized text would be an issue.  But these noSQL solutions might have a property class layer that handles internationalization.  The noSQL solutions are really just key/value storage mechanism.  Just like a property file is a file key/value store.

Comment: I wouldn't call J2EE an "ancient technology".  New J2EE specifications have come out over the last year (EJB 3.1, JSF 2.0, etc., CDI [JSR-299]).  It may not be your "cup of tea", but the framework is certainly not old, or dead.

Comment: @Richard: EJB 3.1 is JavaEE actually. J2EE refers to the specification built upon Java SE 1.4 - there are no annotations, generics and many other convenient features. That is what I meant by ancient. As for JavaEE, I am using it daily, so I wouldn't call it ancient :) It is pretty modern, actually :)

Answer (score 4):

You speak about property files, but at execution time, you are likely to have a resource bundle or something that want a list of key/value pairs (maybe even depending of the locale)

You can store data in whatever format and then use it to contruct the right ressource bundle with it. Even if it comes from memory. So database can perfectly do that, because, properties would all be loaded at startup, cached in JVM memory and that's all. (SELECT * FROM LOCALIZATION_DATA)

Don't use distributed cache for that, the data set you have is likely to be small anyway... what ? Maybe a few MB at worst. And access to that data must be instantaneous once loaded because all views will trigger access to it dozen, or even hundred of time per page.

If you want to update the data without restarting the application just add an administration screen somewhere with a "reload localization data", or even a screen that allow to update this type of data (but save to the file/DB/whatever)

From a workflow point of view, it depend of what you are trying to achieve.

The classic property file is the prefered way of doing this. You put it into versionning, together with the source code so you always have the translation up to date with the code. You want to debug V1.3.0.1 ? just get this version, and you'll use the property file that was used at this time. You added new code that require new keys ? Or just changed they key name for whatever reason ? You know that the code and your locatization information are linked into a coherant state. And this is automatic.

If your data is not under version control, you loose automatic versionning and history of your data. When you deploy/redeploy to a new machine, discrepancy can appear and even prevent the application from running propertly (if a new key is required but not added. This is not great, prone to errors and more manual interventions.

If you really need live updates, and really can't release new version for that, what i would do is to have two source for your data. The standard data, under version control, so your sure all is good for a new install from scratch. And the "customised data", in the server that can override standard values. The customized values are not lost when updating from version to version, because this is just the standard values that are updated.

If the change in the server is purely a one shoot customization, then you just go to the right admin webpage, use the customize localization data screen and that's all.

If the change is something that you'll want to keep for any new installation, you add it 2 time. One time in the server, one time in version control.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use JNDI, or even consider a document repository like JCR for this sort of thing.

Comment: On JCR, we may not necessarily store a full document but property keys and values, also maybe partial documents.   Isn't JNDI more for system properties?  But I will consider those options.

Comment: You could use them for either purpose. For JCR, you'd use a hierarchy like /jcr:root/properties/keyset/key for the xpath, and for JNDI, it'd be similar. There's no prescribed limitation for these APIs' uses in this circumstance.

Comment: Thanks, I will research both options.

Comment: JNDI is a registry for objects which can be distributed across a network via RMI.  I would not simplify it to being a more complicated property bag.

Comment: It can be used that way, sure. But it can be used for whatever you need it to be, including local values.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure a database couldn't handle this, I think what you are really looking for is a cache that can be invalidated when those properties change.  Have you thought about using something like JBoss Infinispan (http://www.jboss.org/infinispan)?  It's extremely simple to use, and can be distributed across multiple application servers.

Infinispan, once configured, can be used like a Map; keep in mind you can configure it to be distributed across a cluster!

If you don't mind using a NoSQL solution, I would recommend something like Redis or Memcache.  Of course, I would advocate that you keep a local cache (why incur the cost of a network call, especially if these properties are not likely to change often?).

Answer (score 1):

***As requested by Berlin Brown, I add another answer, more focussed on it's specific needs :***

From the amount of data you need (like a thousand of entries), you just need to load your property file at startup by specifying a remote URL.

Data is cached in JVM memory for maximum performance.

Depending on your workflow you then have a background process that check for update on a regalar basis (let say each minute, hour, whatever is enough for you) or you can have a "button" in administration "refresh localization data" developper use when an update is needed.

No need for database. No need for memcached, no need for NoSQL. a simple URL accessible from production server. In term of security and dev it is easier, faster and more flexible.

Implementation details: if you use the standard format, you'll have a file per language/contry. Don't forget to update for all languages or bundle them together (using a zip for exemple).

Comment: Your solution makes sense and I just never thought about it.  Of course, you have the issue of setting up some kind of remote property file and managing updates.  Also, will the classpath references to the URL property file work the same.